# Wörterbuch für schweizerisches Standarddeutsch

Tags: dictionary, swiss-standard-german

Der *Duden* gilt als Standardwerk für deutsches Deutsch, und dieses Buch versucht auch das Vokabular der beiden anderen Standardvarietäten der deutschen Sprache abzudecken, was ihm aber nicht vollständig gelingt.
<sub>Es fehlen z.B.: Die Abwasch (= Synonym für Spülbecken), der Pfiff (= 0,2 Liter Bier), der Spritzer/G’spritzte/Gespritzte (Mischung aus Wein und Wasser), budern (koitieren), Nachzipf (Wiederholungsprüfung) und viele andere Austriazismen.</sub>

Das *Österreichische Wörterbuch* (ÖWB) ist das Standardwerk für österreichisches Deutsch, und im Gegensatz zum *Duden* handelt es sich hierbei sogar um ein amtliches und somit verbindliches Nachschlagewerk. (Verbindlich für österreichische Bundesbeamte und Schüler.) Das ÖWB nimmt auch Bezug zum deutschen Deutsch, weil es vor allem durch Printmedien und Fernsehen auch überall dort gegenwärtig ist, wo österreichisches Deutsch unterrichtet wird und Amtssprache ist (also in Österreich und in einem kleinen Teil Italiens, nämlich in Südtirol).

Allerdings ist mir kein derartiges Standard-Wörterbuch für schweizerisches Deutsch bekannt. Ich suche also ein Wörterbuch, in dem Wörter wie *Bettmümpfeli* oder *jenst* zu finden sind, und das die an Schweizer und Liechtensteiner Schulen unterrichtete Varietät der deutschen Sprache wiedergibt, die in diesen beiden Staaten auch Amtssprache ist.

Nachtrag:
Ich suche ganz ausdrücklich ein vollständiges Wörterbuch des schweizerischen Standarddeutsch. Also keine Sammlung von Dialektwörtern, sondern ein Buch, das im Schulunterricht als Referenzwerk Verwendung findet, so wie der Duden in Deutschland und das ÖWB in Österreich.

Comment: Pfiff gibt es übrjgens auch in Deutschland (wahrscheinlich überall, denn ich kenne es aus Augsburg und Berlin), allerdings ist die Bedeutung spezifischer. Es ist ein nicht volles Glas Bier, das einem der Mensch hinter der Theke spät am Abend aufs Haus anbietet.

Comment: Nicht was Du suchst, da es nur ein Zusatz ist, aber Google liefert mir http://www.duden.de/Shop/Schweizerhochdeutsch

Comment: @CarstenS: Interessant. In Österreich gibt es Bier in diesen Standard-Größen: Krügerl (auch »Krügel« oder »großes Bier«) = 0,5 Liter. Seidl (»kleines Bier«) = 0,3 Liter. Der Pfiff mit 0,2 Liter wird auf Bestellung überall serviert, steht aber selten auf der Karte, muss aber selbstverständlich bezahlt werden. Wenn der Wirt ein Glas auf seine Kosten ausgibt, bestimmt meist er die Größe. Das Getränk geht dann »aufs Haus«, hat aber keine spezielle Bezeichnung. Bierlokale bieten auch als Übergrößen den Stiefel (2,0 Liter = 4 Krügerl) und den Humpen (5,0 Liter = 10 Krügerl) an.

Comment: Es ist natürlich auch möglich, dass ich das Wort einfach nur aus diesem Kontext kenne.

Comment: Ok, noch einmal zum Pfiff: Da muss man wohl Gepflogenheit von [Einheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfiff_(Einheit)) trennen. Letztere war mir unbekannt, wieder etwas gelernt. Vor der Metrisierung war ein Pfiff in Wien wohl etwas kleiner als 0,2l.

Comment: @CarstenS: Stimmt. Ein Pfiff war früher 1/2 Seidl (also 0,15 Liter) oder 1/3 Krügerl (0,167 Liter).

Comment: @poitroae: So eine Liste ist nett, trifft aber das, wonach ich gefragt habe, aus zwei Gründen nicht: Erstens: Diese Liste enthält nur Wörter, die nur in der Schweiz gebräuchlich sind. Wörter, die im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum in Verwendung sind (und somit ebenfalls auch in schweizerischen Zeitungen stehen, wie z.B. »gehen«, »Luft«, »grün«, »der«, »fünf«) fehlen in dieser Liste. Da auch Schweizer diese Wörter in ihre Zeitungen drucken, ist jede Wörtersammlung, die diese Wörter nicht enthält, kein vollständiges Wörterbuch.

Comment: @poitroae: (Fortsetzung) Zweitens: Die Liste enthält sehr viele Ausdrücke, die kein Standarddeutsch sind, sondern Dialekt- oder Scherz-Ausdrücke sind, wie z.B. »Affegnagi« (für »Banane«), »Araber« als verballhornter Name für ein bestimmtes Restaurant in Bern (»Aarbergerhof«) und »Alpepizza« (für »Kuhfladen«). Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, das diese Wörter in einer seriösen Schweizer Tageszeitung gedruckt werden, oder von einem Nachrichtensprecher bei den Abendnachrichten verwendet werden. Ich zweifle auch daran, dass Schweizer Schüler diese Wörter im offiziellen Unterricht lernen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut den [Schreibweisungen](https://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04915/05016/index.html?lang=de) der Schweizerischen Bundeskanzlei ist für amtliche Texte der [Leitfaden zur deutschen Rechtschreibung](https://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04915/05018/index.html?lang=de) verbindlich.

Zusätzlich können die Rechtschreibwörterbücher

- Duden Band 1: Die deutsche Rechtschreibung. 24. Auflage oder neuer. Mannheim: Dudenverlag

und

- Wahrig Rechtschreibung: Die deutsche Rechtschreibung. 8. Auflage oder neuer. Gütersloh/München: Wissenmedia

verwendet werden. (Wenn Duden und Wahrig andere Varianten als der Rechtschreibleitfaden bevorzugen, so geht der Rechtschreibleitfaden vor.)

Auf ein etwa mit dem ÖWB vergleichbares schweizerisches Wörterbuch enthalten die Schreibweisungen dagegen keinen Hinweis.

Allerdings gehen die Schreibweisungen ausdrücklich auf Helvetismen ein

> Insbesondere für Erlasse, aber auch für die übrigen amtlichen Texte gilt, dass sie in erster Linie von Schweizerinnen und Schweizern verstanden werden müssen. Deshalb sind grundsätzlich schweizerische Ausdrücke zu verwenden. «Helvetismen» sind aber nicht etwa Dialektwörter, die in einem standard- oder hochsprachlichen Text nichts zu suchen haben, sondern regionale Varianten der Standard- oder Hochsprache – wie es übrigens auch «Austriazismen» und «Teutonismen» gibt.

und verweisen für zusätzliche Informationen zu Helvetismen auf

- Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen. Die Standardsprache in Österreich, der Schweiz und Deutschland sowie in Liechtenstein, Luxemburg, Ostbelgien und Südtirol. Berlin / New York: Verlag Walter de Gruyter

und

- Bickel, Hans / Landolt, Christoph. Schweizerhochdeutsch. Wörterbuch der Standardsprache in der deutschen Schweiz. Mannheim / Zürich: Dudenverlag.

sowie auf eine knappe Behandlung bei

- Heuer: Heuer, Walter / Flückiger, Max / Gallmann, Peter. Richtiges Deutsch. Vollständige Grammatik und Rechtschreiblehre. Zürich: Verlag Neue Zürcher Zeitung.

Answer (score 3):

Ein derartiges vollständiges Wörterbuch des Schweizer Hochdeutsch gibt es meines Wissens nicht. Es gibt jedoch eine Anzahl Wörterbücher, die dieses Gebiet jeweils zu einem Teil abdecken:

- Der *Duden*-Band [*Schweizerhochdeutsch: Wörterbuch der Standardsprache in der deutschen Schweiz*](http://www.duden.de/Shop/Schweizerhochdeutsch) kommt dem Gesuchten nahe, da es ausschließlich die Schweizer Standardsprache behandelt. Allerdings enthält es keine vollständige Wortliste, sondern nur Wörter oder Wendungen, die nicht gemeindeutsch sind (also nicht im ganzen deutschen Sprachgebiet vorkommen). Daher ist es auch sehr dünn, unter hundert Seiten, und aus ihm ist – auch in Kombination mit einem gesamtdeutschen Wörterbuch – nicht zu ersehen, welche Wörter in der Schweiz *nicht* gebräuchlich sind. Jeder Eintrag gibt eine kurze Definition des Worts.
- Das [*Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen: Die Standardsprache in Österreich, der Schweiz und Deutschland sowie in Liechtenstein, Luxemburg, Ostbelgien und Südtirol*](http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/14332) ([Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variantenw%C3%B6rterbuch_des_Deutschen)) verfolgt einen ähnlichen kontrastiven Ansatz, behandelt aber die drei Hauptvarietäten gleichrangig und geht, sofern es Unterschiede gibt, auch auf die anderen Varietäten und auf regionale Unterschiede innerhalb Deutschlands und Österreichs ein. Jeder Eintrag beschreibt das Verbreitungsgebiet des Worts, gibt eine Definition und verweist auf Entsprechungen in den anderen deutschen Varietäten.
- Das umfangreichste Wörterbuch zum Schweizer Deutsch ist das [*Schweizerische Idiotikon: Schweizerdeutsches Wörterbuch*](https://www.idiotikon.ch/) ([Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerisches_Idiotikon)). Sein Thema ist aber nicht die Standardsprache, sondern der Dialektwortschatz. Trotzdem kann es hilfreich sein, wenn es um die Bedeutung von Helvetismen geht, sofern sie aus dem Dialekt stammen und nicht etwa aus dem Französischen entlehnt sind.

Comment: Von den Wörtern aus der Frage kennt das _Variantenwörterbuch_ übrigens _Abwasch_ (sowohl _die_ als auch _der_), _Spritzer_, _Gespritzter_, _Nachzipf_ (und _Nachzapf_), sowie _Bettmümpfeli_. Hingegen steht _jenste_ in keinem der drei Wörterbücher, woraus ich schließe, daß es 1. nicht als standardsprachlich gilt und 2. relativ jung ist (das Idiotikon, wie alle diese Großwörterbücher, ist ein Jahrhundertwerk).